# Jquery content popup not displaying correctly

Tags: jquery, popup, tooltip

I have multiple tooltips on the page but the first one is generating multiple versions and from the wrong content in the end (It's displaying the content from the second one). What's wrong with my function that it's doing the mouseover event multiple times and looking at the wrong content?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $(".noteshoverbtn").each(function() {
      var btn = $(this);
          html = $("html");
          tip     = btn.html();
          tooltip = $("<div class='notescontent'></div>");
          closebtn = $("<div>", {text: "X", "class": "close"});
          if( !tip || tip == "" )
            return false;
          btn.empty();
          tooltip.css("opacity", 0).html(tip).appendTo(btn).hide();
          tooltip.append(closebtn);
      btn.mouseenter(function() {
        console.log("mouseenter");
        if( $( window ).width() < tooltip.outerWidth() * 1.5 )
            tooltip.css("max-width", $( window ).width() / 2 );
        else
          tooltip.css("max-width", 340 );
        var pos_left = btn.offset().left + ( btn.outerWidth() / 2 ) - ( tooltip.outerWidth() / 2 ),
            pos_top = btn.offset().top - tooltip.outerHeight() - 20;
            pos_page_top   = btn.offset().top - tooltip.scrollTop() - 20;
            scrollTop    = $(window).scrollTop(),
            elementOffset = btn.offset().top,
            distance       = (elementOffset - scrollTop);
        if( pos_left < 0 ) {
          pos_left = btn.offset().left + btn.outerWidth() / 2 - 20;
          tooltip.addClass("left");
        }else
          tooltip.removeClass("left");
        if( pos_left + tooltip.outerWidth() > $( window ).width() ) {
          pos_left = btn.offset().left - tooltip.outerWidth() + btn.outerWidth() / 2 + 20;
          tooltip.addClass("right");
        }else
          tooltip.removeClass("right");
        if (pos_top < 0 || distance < elementOffset) {
          var pos_top = btn.offset().top + btn.outerHeight();
          tooltip.addClass("top");
        }else
          tooltip.removeClass("top'");
          tooltip.css( { left: pos_left, top: pos_top } ).animate( { top: "+=14", opacity: 1 }, 50 ).show();
          btn.addClass("active");
      });

      btn.mouseleave(function() {
        tooltip.animate( { top: "-=14", opacity: 0 }, 50 ).hide();
        btn.removeClass("active");
        console.log("mouseleave");
      });

      $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 27)
          tooltip.animate( { top: "-=14", opacity: 0 }, 50 ).hide();
          btn.removeClass("active");
      });

      if($("html").hasClass("touch")){
        console.log("html has touch class");
        //console.log(tooltip);
        $(document).on("touchstart", function () {
          if(btn.hasClass("active")){
            tooltip.animate( { top: "-=14", opacity: 0 }, 50 ).hide();
            btn.removeClass("active");
            console.log("mobileclose");
          }
        });
      }

    $(".notescontent a").on("touchstart", function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); });

  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Snarf/8j455a6p/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's a little hard to read the logic, however from what i can see it looks like you have some variables without 'var' in front of them so they are global which might cause some issues.  Also your binding for document keyup, document touchstart, and notescontent a touchstart are happening inside the each, which would potentially (and is in two of the cases) be multiple bindings which can also cause issues.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jLg9opkf/

Comment: Thank you both! That worked.